# What are the completion rewards in Splatoon 3?

Tags: splatoon-3

I did the whole game 100% in one go so now I don't know what I got for what.

I even did every station with every weapon, and have no clue what I got for it.

So what are the completion rewards in splatoon 3? What do you get for each action?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I looked deeper into it, and heres what I got.

### By beating the final boss

You get the hero shot, headset, shirt and shoes replica. Also a sticker for your name plate. On the online app, you will also get a wallpaper.

[image]

### By beating every level once

You get access to the secret kettle (Champion's road kinda thing; super hard level).

[image]

### By beating the secret kettle

You get the bear ears headset and the title Alternan World Champ. Also a sticker for your nameplate.

[image]
[image]

### By collecting every collectible

The collectibles are their own reward. Nothing more is given.

- CDs: Changes the music of the zone
- Artifacts: Can be used in your locker
- Sardinium: Getting them all means you can finish the upgrade tree (there is exactly enough sardinium to finish it)
- Sunken Scrolls: Lore.
- Card packs: For the card game
- Extra eggs: Gives you extra currency to open/retry levels.

### By surveying every square of the map

Each zone gives you a sticker of the zone.After surveying all areas, you get another wallpaper on the app.

[image]

### By beating every stage with every available set

You get nothing. Good day to you sir.

Comment: Kudos for completing everything it in just few days!

Comment: Its maybe a 15hour game for the single player, 100%... And i wake up at 4 to feed my baby son, then cant sleep so i got 8 hours of gaming time

Answer (score 1):

According to GameWith and their [Splatoon 3 wiki guide](https://gamewith.net/splatoon3/article/show/35086):

> You will receive a Hero Shot Replica after completing the Hero Mode to the end. The performance is the same as Splattershot.

[image]

---

After completing the

> Secret kettle level

you get:

- A title
  [image]
- A Teddy Band gear
  [image]

Comment: This "completion" does not mean 100%. Since I've only done completing hero mode, but I already have the Hero Shot Replica. After defeating the last boss, player is able to access the secret stage, but completing that isn't needed to receive the Hero Shot Replica, player just need to defeat the last boss. I don't know what'll happen after the completion of the secret stage, though. Perhaps some gears and/or titles?

Comment: Forgot to mention: defeating last boss also gives you some gears, replica version of gear that hero uses. My advice... don't trust GameWith. They're notorious in Japan (GameWith is Japanese company) because of the lack of information, and they actually don't much play the game, so they often writes incorrect/insufficient article.

Comment: @Skye-AT Sadly I ordered my copy weeks ago and I'm still waiting for it, I'd be glad to write a proved answer... I added the secret stage completion reward, if that's enough for you

Comment: Ouch. I didn't mean to spoil it, I thought you've already done the hero mode, sorry for that. Have fun in your game, it's got so much improvement in every aspect.

Comment: @Skye-AT no worries :) there's often a special stage like that. And regarding the reward, that was a bit disappointing anyway, so nothing to spoil

Comment: @pinckerman I once had a game I ordered on amazon that didnt get delivered day 1. I just bought it from the store, and returned the seal copy to the store when I received it from Amazon. Said something like 'Oh hey I bought it but also received it for my birthday'. I guess check if they take returns of sealed copies before doing so.