# Can’t get the After Alterna after beating all the levels

Tags: splatoon-3

I beat all the levels and got all hero gears, but for some reason the sixth Alterna log was not analyzed and I didn’t get the After Alterna level.

Comment: Figured out there was a hidden level called enemy ink is lava

Comment: If the answer helped you, feel free to click the check to confirm it as a right answer! Will help the next person that comes trough wondering the same thing!

Answer (score 4):

Like mentioned [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/399242/what-are-the-completion-rewards-in-splatoon-3), the hero suit is only given on game completion, not completion of every level.

If you don't have the secret kettle, you have missed a kettle somewhere. And since the 6th log seems incomplete, it's in that region.

So I guess explore the last map, you are missing a level.

Good to note too: The kettle levels shown on the list are only those that were unlocked. But they are numbered. So look at the list, if you have everything they should be 1-2-3-4-5-6. If it jumps a number, you know which you are missing, and then can go lookup a guide to know where it is.